# Какой формат scanf использовать для ввода bool

Tags: c

Всем привет!

```
scanf("%i", &reverse_sort);
```

Компилятор ругается на несовместимость спецификатора и вводимых данных:

> /home/yura/gitclone/c_git/arr_sort.c|15|предупреждение: format «%i» expects argument of type «int *», but argument 2 has type «_Bool *» [-Wformat=]|

Comment: Так а `_Bool` как у вас определён?

Comment: stdbool.h, поэтому bool имя_переменной.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Судя по обсуждениям в интернете, никак, `scanf` не умеет bool. Но подождём специалистов.

Comment: Ну, bool это новомодное изобретение для Си. Раньше его просто не было. Внутри это char (или unsigned char, короче 1 байт. целого типа) Так что, вводите, например, значения во вспомогательную int переменную и присваивайте.

Comment: @avp, или просто изначально использовать `int` :-) Если ситуация позволяет, конечно.

Comment: @klopp, можно. Я, например, такого слова -- bool -- вообще не использую. Если мне нужны *биты* -- работаю с ними в массиве char[], если один -- int или char.

Comment: @avp, я подумываю, что char лучше использовать. А вообще, кто-нибудь бул использует?

Comment: Встречал в каких-то опенсурсных исходниках не один раз. Но в принципе в рамках C вообще никакого смысла не вижу.

Comment: @Abyx, поправь пожалуйста заголовок вопроса "какой формат использовать для ввода данных переменную bool в си?". Вот так точнее будет, мне кажется

Comment: BTW, ещё есть такая мысля: по-хорошему, `scanf()` вообще мало где нужен :) По мне так вообще нигде. Даже не могу вспомнить, когда последний раз использовал что-то из этого семейства.

Answer (score 3):

Один из случаев, когда разные части стандарта подтягиваются с разной скоростью. Не существует пока спецификатора для bool-переменных. Корректный способ сделать то, что Вы хотите:

```
int temp;
bool reverse_sort;
scanf("%i", &temp);
reverse_sort = temp;
```

Comment: Да и так можно. Но мне кажется лишняя переменная, можно делать как предложил автор снизу. А лучше использовать старый, добрый char

Comment: И чем `char` лучше  инта? По мне так наоборот, с `int` возни меньше, а эффективности больше :)

Comment: @gnuvse: Это если `_Bool` не определён как `int` в данной реализации. Подумайте, что будет со значением `257`.

Comment: @gnuvse Я ответил на вопрос. Если бы вопрос был: как сделать правильно, я бы ответил, что надо использовать `int` вместо `bool`, как это делали в Си последние 45 лет.

Comment: @VladD переполнение. Так можно проверять входные данные.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, да, я видел. Я не могу пока лайки ставить, из-за низкого рейтинга

Comment: @Abyx, к сожалению, я пока ничего не могу делать. Спасибо

Comment: @gnuvse: Совершенно верно. Именно поэтому читать в `char` может оказаться неверно, если `_Bool` на вашей системе — `int`.

Comment: @VladD, это интересно, надо бы проверить на досуге. Спасибо.

Comment: 257, преобразованное к `bool`, совершенно корректно превратится в 1. Хуже будет с 256 - оно может превратиться в 0, если `bool` является всего лишь синонимом для `char`. Поэтому последнюю строчку я бы на всякий случай написал как `reverse_sort = !!temp;`

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko, у Вас тут ошибка: `%I` - не то же самое, что `%i`. В данном случае следует использовать `%i`.

Comment: @mega Исправил. Это не ошибка, это опечатка. :)

Answer (score 2):

Такого формата [нет](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). Считывайте `int` - а потом уже приводите к `bool`.

Comment: Это если значение записано как 0/1, а не false/true.

Comment: А в `stdbool.h` они явно задефайнены как 0 и 1.

Comment: Сделал, работает, правда путаница типов. Но я так понял, что любое не нулевое число при приведение типов он приводт к 1?

Comment: Типа да, только не к 1, а к `true`. Но только пока речь идёт о значениях, а не об указателях, как в случае со `scanf()`.